# word meaning - articles and tidbits

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

When referring to a piece of information, as in "articles and tidbits," does the word *tidbit* always refer to juicy, gossipy, or salacious information?

Comment: The original meaning is about food- "tender bit", https://www.etymonline.com/word/tidbit

Comment: I know, but I'm asking about its other sense.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tidbit

Answer (score 4):

A *tidbit* of information is a direct analogy to food - it is small and attractive. It is any small piece of information that is expected to be of particular interest. This might mean it's salacious or gossipy, but it might also be a key piece of information in an academic study - though it would rarely be referred to using that term in formal writing.